# Enum name is saved to the database instead of enum value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an enum:

```
    public enum AccountType {
       CURRENT_ACCOUNT("currentAccount"),
   
       private final String name;

       AccountType(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }

       @JsonValue
       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return getName();
       }
   }
```

I have the fiel annotated with @Enumerate:

```
@Column(name = "account_type", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private AccountType accountType;
```

Yet when I am saving the values to the database, the name of the enum ("CURRENT_ACCOUNT") is saved, rather than the property value of the enum ("currentAccount"), what should be done, for it to be saved as the "currentAccount" and not "CURRENT_ACCOUNT".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that below annotation @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) indicate to your ORM (JPA) to save String and not default numeric enum.

If you want to :

- Save numeric enum then remove "EnumType.STRING"
- Or save String but with specific format then check with your override of "toString()". Stop to re-write "name" property